# Remove line breaks based on delimiter

Tags: r

I have a messy, |-delimited file that I want to clean up. A good row looks like this:

```
 1,|some data|,|more data|,|some numbers|
```

And several messy lines that have linebreaks where they don't belong

```
 10,|some data|,|lots of text blah
 blah blah blah
 and more text
 sometimes text stretches across many lines|,|some numbers|
```

As shown, the number of columns is theoretically the same but the data is messy in a way that there are linebreaks where they shouldn't be.

I would like to read in the file so that the values between | are all stored in the same vector (in a dataframe).

I am currently reading in the file using

```
 data <- read_delim("myfile.txt", delim = "|")
 data <- data[, c(-1, -3, -5)] #to remove the columns just containing commas
```

But this gives me lots of incorrectly parsed rows.

I was thinking of telling R somehow that I would like to delete all linebreaks before the 6th |. Any ideas on how to do that or how to read in this messy file in any other way?

I should add that the file is very large and manual tidying is not an option.

Comment: How big of a file are we talking about? Can you read all the text in and then do a text replacement, or is too massive? e.g. `txt <- paste(readLines("filename.txt", collapse="\n"); read.table(text=gsub("[^|]\n", " ", txt), sep="|")`

Comment: The file is about 500mb or about 3.2 million lines (including messy lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution seems to be

```
library(readr)
read_delim("file.txt", delim = ",", quote = "|", col_names = F)
```

Where `quote` tells `read_delim` the beginning and end of the vector even when it goes over multiple lines in the source file. The `delim` argument specifies that the strings indicated by | are separated by commas.

It also works with `read.delim`

```
read.delim("file.txt", sep = ",", quote = "|",  header = F)
```

and with `data.table`'s `fread` for maximum speed

```
library(data.table)
fread("file.txt", sep = ",", quote = "|",  header = F)
```

---

**Data**

*file.txt*

```
1,|some data|,|more data|,|some numbers|
2,|some data|,|lots of text blah
blah blah blah
and more text
sometimes text stretches across many lines|,|some numbers|
```

---

**Result**

```
# X1         X2                                                                                                               X3           X4
# 1  some data                                                                                                        more data some numbers
# 2  some data                        lots of text blah blah blah blah and more text sometimes text stretches across many lines some numbers
```

Comment: Does this also work with plain old `read.delim` too?

Answer (score 1):

Your data seems to follow a few patterns:

1. Column separators are either `,|` or `|,|`
2. Row separators are `|\n` (bar followed by newline)
3. `\n` may appear randomly mid-column

If you can identify such patterns, you can process the file step-by-step in order to get it to the more common csv format:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- readr::read_file("file.txt") %>%   # read the file as a string
  str_replace_all(",\\||\\|,\\|", ",") %>% # replace all column separators with commas
  str_replace_all("\n", "") %>%            # replace all newlines with empty strings
  str_replace_all("\\|", "\n") %>%         # replace all remaining bars with newlines
  read.csv(text = ., header = FALSE)       # read the .csv string into a data frame
```

Using this pipeline, we can go from a file that looks like this:

```
1,|some data|,|more data|,|some numbers|
10,|some data|,|lots of text blah
 blah blah blah
 and more text
 sometimes text stretches across many lines|,|some numbers|
10,|some data|,|lots of text blah
 blah blah blah
 and more text
 sometimes text stretches across many lines|,|some numbers|
1,|some data|,|more data|,|some numbers|
```

To the following data frame:

```
  V1        V2                                                                                        V3           V4
1  1 some data                                                                                 more data some numbers
2 10 some data lots of text blah blah blah blah and more text sometimes text stretches across many lines some numbers
3 10 some data lots of text blah blah blah blah and more text sometimes text stretches across many lines some numbers
4  1 some data                                                                                 more data some numbers
```

Comment: Would ```read_delim("file.txt", delim = ",", quote = "|", col_names = F)``` also work? I just read somewhere that this is a way of reading in these files.

Comment: @TeaTree yep, that seems to work! What a beautifully concise solution.

Answer (score 1):

Following @thelatemale's idea further we could use `readLines` and collapse into one string using `paste`.

Then we apply `strsplit` two times. First, splitting the string at it's line numbers (they get lost but I assume they're consecutive). Second, split the strings in the list at `|,|` and clean a little using `trinws`. Finally just `rbind` the thing.

```
txt <- paste(readLines(con="R/messy.txt"), collapse=" ")
rr <- el(strsplit(txt, "\\b\\d*\\,\\|"))[-1]
rr <- strsplit(trimws(rr, whitespace="[\\|| ]"), "|,|", fixed=TRUE)
res <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, rr))
```

### Result

```
# res
#           V1                                                                                                               V2           V3
# 1  some data                                                                                                        more data some numbers
# 2  some data                                                                                                        more data some numbers
# 3  some data                                                                                                        more data some numbers
# 4  some data                        lots of text blah blah blah blah and more text sometimes text stretches across many lines some numbers
# 5  some data                                                                                                        more data some numbers
# 6  some data lots of text blah blah blah blah and more text, this time with comma, sometimes text stretches across many lines some numbers
# 7  some data                                                                                                        more data some numbers
# 8  some data                        lots of text blah blah blah blah and more text sometimes text stretches across many lines some numbers
# 9  some data                                                                                                        more data some numbers
# 10 some data                                                                                                        more data some numbers
```

---

*messy.txt*

```
1,|some data|,|more data|,|some numbers|
2,|some data|,|more data|,|some numbers|
3,|some data|,|more data|,|some numbers|
4,|some data|,|lots of text blah
blah blah blah
and more text
sometimes text stretches across many lines|,|some numbers|
5,|some data|,|more data|,|some numbers|
6,|some data|,|lots of text blah
blah blah blah
and more text, this time with comma,
sometimes text stretches across many lines|,|some numbers|
7,|some data|,|more data|,|some numbers|
8,|some data|,|lots of text blah
blah blah blah
and more text
sometimes text stretches across many lines|,|some numbers|
9,|some data|,|more data|,|some numbers|
10,|some data|,|more data|,|some numbers|
```